# Can I insert a '0' in `np.linspace`?

Tags: python, numpy, linspace

Suppose I have this equally spaced 'darray':

```
epslist = np.linspace(-0.1,0.1,12)
```

Is there a way I can 'insert' a '0' in this 'darray' with the 'ordered' position? By that, in this case, '0' should be added to the middle of `epslist`, instead of in the end. I don't really know how to do that and which tools I could use. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You won't need to insert anything if you use an odd number like 11 or 13 instead of 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use advanced indexing and concatenation for example:

```
epslist = np.concatenate((epslist[epslist<0], [0], epslist[epslist>0]))
```